# Why are all my images coming out much darker in the front end than they are in the back end?

Tags: magento-1.7, image, backend, frontend

Why are all my images, on http://www.theswordshop.co.uk coming out much darker in the front end than they are in the back end?

I'm on Magento 1.7.0.2

I'm also having an issue on a sister website http://theknightshoptrade.com/index.php/ They're both on different installs, with different themes and I don't believe they actually share any extensions

My images are all JPEG, 72dpi, dimensions of 650px x 650px, RGB and 8bits.

Here's an example of what my images look in the backend compared to the front end:

*Image in correct colours (as seen in the backend)*
[image: Backend]

*Image desaturated (as is in the frontend*
[image: Frontend]

Comment: Your site isn't accessible, does it need some hosts entry?

Comment: Go through your list of modules, one is definitely responsible.

Comment: Sorry, should have been .co.uk - Edited and corrected

Comment: I'm also having an issue on a sister website http://theknightshoptrade.com/index.php/ They're both on different installs, with different themes and I don't believe they actually share any extensions

Comment: I'm also having an issue on my website https://swordskingdom.co.uk/ They're both on different installs, with different themes and I don't believe they actually share any extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woohoo! Fixed it by saving the JPEG using Photoshop's "Save for Web" option (ALT+SHIFT+CTRL+S) which doesn't explain why the images were coming out different in the backend it does however fix my issue going forwards. It'd be nice to know WHY it was happening but the fact that I've found a fix for the issue is enough for me!

Comment: Congrats br0.   i'm happy for you.

Comment: It will probably be down to the colour profile settings the image was originally saved with. When resized for the frontend, the GD2 driver was probably using a different profile for the resized image.

Answer (score 1):

The images are resized on the fly by a library called GD2. 
Does the image looks bad in admin when it is displayed as a thumbnail?
Does it happen on other server or when you run the store on your local machine (try same image with a clean Magento installation)? 
Does it happen with different images? Try uploading PNG instead of JPEG. You might want to try Imagemagick instead and see if it helps https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Perfect_Watermarks

Comment: The image looks perfect in the admin, it's only when displayed in the frontend that it desaturates. I've tried with a clean install for a different site on a different server, using the same and different images and I'm still having the same issue. I'll give it a go with PNG, although PNG of photographs tend to be quite large, which is why I've tried to stick to JPEG. If not I'll try your suggestion of Imagemagick and see if that helps at all. Thanks very much!

Comment: PNG didn't make a difference so it looks like I'm going to have to give imagemagick a go. I'm surprised I can't find anyone else having this issue as I'm having the issue on 3 different stores, with two different themes, all with different plugins, on two different servers with the images created on two different computers!